# Why I Recieving Too Many Root Mails for my Wordpress website?

Tags: wordpress, cpanel, whm

I have wordpress website and it is connected to cPandel WHM and I constantly recieve this mail

Time:                    Thu Aug  3 19:02:31 2023 +0300
1 Min Load Avg:          11.33
5 Min Load Avg:          11.33
15 Min Load Avg:         11.37
Running/Total Processes: 18/296

And this is the ps.txt file

```
Output from ps:
USER       PID %CPU %MEM    VSZ   RSS TTY      STAT START   TIME COMMAND
 root         2  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Apr20   0:01 [kthreadd]
 root         4  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   Apr20   0:00  \_ [kworker/0:0H]
 root         6  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Apr20   2:36  \_ [ksoftirqd/0]
 root         7  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Apr20   0:29  \_ [migration/0]
 root         8  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Apr20   0:00  \_ [rcu_bh]
 root         9  0.1  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Apr20 243:23  \_ [rcu_sched]
 root        10  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   Apr20   0:00  \_ [lru-add-drain]
 root        11  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Apr20   0:55  \_ [watchdog/0]
 root        12  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Apr20   1:14  \_ [watchdog/1]
 root        13  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Apr20   0:29  \_ [migration/1]
 root        14  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Apr20  19:33  \_ [ksoftirqd/1]
 root        16  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   Apr20   0:00  \_ [kworker/1:0H]
 root        18  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Apr20   0:00  \_ [kdevtmpfs]
 root        19  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   Apr20   0:00  \_ [netns]
 root        20  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Apr20   0:12  \_ [khungtaskd]
 root        21  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   Apr20   0:00  \_ [writeback]
 root        22  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   Apr20   0:00  \_ [kintegrityd]
 root        23  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   Apr20   0:00  \_ [bioset]
 root        24  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   Apr20   0:00  \_ [bioset]
 root        25  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   Apr20   0:00  \_ [bioset]
 root        26  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   Apr20   0:00  \_ [kblockd]
 root        27  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   Apr20   0:00  \_ [md]
 root        28  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   Apr20   0:00  \_ [edac-poller]
 root        29  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   Apr20   0:00  \_ [watchdogd]
 root        35  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Apr20  16:32  \_ [kswapd0]
 root        36  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        SN   Apr20   0:00  \_ [ksmd]
 root        37  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        SN   Apr20   1:12  \_ [khugepaged]
 root        38  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   Apr20   0:00  \_ [crypto]
 root        46  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   Apr20   0:00  \_ [kthrotld]
 root        48  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   Apr20   0:00  \_ [kmpath_rdacd]
 root        49  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   Apr20   0:00  \_ [kaluad]
 root        50  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   Apr20   0:00  \_ [kpsmoused]
 root        51  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   Apr20   0:00  \_ [ipv6_addrconf]
 root        64  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   Apr20   0:00  \_ [deferwq]
 root       111  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Apr20   0:28  \_ [kauditd]
 root       198  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   Apr20   0:00  \_ [rpciod]
 root       199  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   Apr20   0:00  \_ [xprtiod]
 root       263  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   Apr20   0:00  \_ [ata_sff]
 root       273  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Apr20   0:00  \_ [scsi_eh_0]
 root       274  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   Apr20   0:00  \_ [scsi_tmf_0]
 root       275  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Apr20   0:00  \_ [scsi_eh_1]
 root       276  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   Apr20   0:00  \_ [scsi_tmf_1]
 root       279  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   Apr20  11:47  \_ [kworker/1:1H]
 root       290  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   Apr20  11:37  \_ [kworker/0:1H]
 root       291  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Apr20  49:07  \_ [jbd2/vda3-8]
 root       292  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   Apr20   0:00  \_ [ext4-rsv-conver]
 root       452  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Apr20   2:22  \_ [hwrng]
 root       536  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   Apr20   0:00  \_ [ttm_swap]
 root       574  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Apr20   0:00  \_ [jbd2/vda1-8]
 root       575  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   Apr20   0:00  \_ [ext4-rsv-conver]
 root       577  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   Apr20   0:00  \_ [kvm-irqfd-clean]
 root       825  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   Apr20   3:29  \_ [loop0]
 root       827  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Apr20   1:08  \_ [jbd2/loop0-8]
 root       828  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   Apr20   0:00  \_ [ext4-rsv-conver]
 root      6382  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    10:02   0:00  \_ [kworker/u4:2]
 root     21347  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    12:31   0:00  \_ [kworker/u4:1]
 root     50985  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    16:43   0:00  \_ [kworker/0:2]
 root     55870  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    17:25   0:00  \_ [kworker/0:0]
 root     57775  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    17:42   0:00  \_ [kworker/1:1]
 root     58541  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    17:48   0:00  \_ [kworker/1:2]
 root     59774  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    17:58   0:00  \_ [kworker/1:0]
 root         1  0.0  0.0 191532  3552 ?        Ss   Apr20 112:50 /usr/lib/systemd/systemd --system --deserialize 22
 root       611  0.0  0.0  55528   284 ?        S<sl Apr20   1:28 /sbin/auditd
 dbus       641  0.0  0.0  60388  1096 ?        Ss   Apr20  39:27 /usr/bin/dbus-daemon --system --address=systemd: --nofork --nopidfile --systemd-activation
 root      1103  0.0  0.0 100984   448 ?        Ss   Apr20   2:46 /sbin/dhclient -1 -q -lf /var/lib/dhclient/dhclient--eth0.lease -pf /var/run/dhclient-eth0.pid -H mail eth0
 root      1172  0.0  0.7 255488 28876 ?        Ss   Apr20  99:48 cpsrvd (SSL) - waiting for connections                   
 root     60191  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        Z    18:02   0:00  \_ [cpsrvd (SSL) - ] <defunct>
 root      1384  0.0  0.4 205340 17344 ?        Ss   Apr20  60:20 tailwatchd
 root      1386  0.0  0.2 185812 10720 ?        Ss   Apr20  73:35 cPhulkd - processor
 root     58014  0.0  0.2 151864 10384 ?        S    17:43   0:00  \_ cPhulkd - dbprocessor
 root      1387  0.0  0.1 167448  4200 ?        Ss   Apr20   6:15 dnsadmin - dormant mode
 root      1390  0.0  0.1 183892  6068 ?        Ss   Apr20   2:14 cpdavd - accepting connections on: 2091, 2077, 2078 (dormant)
 named    44466  0.0  0.3 376080 14196 ?        Ssl  Jul05   0:26 /usr/sbin/named -u named -c /etc/named.conf
 root     44583  0.0  0.0 111300   924 ?        Ss   Jul05   0:00 /usr/sbin/sshd -D
 root     51275  0.0  0.0  42912   328 ?        Ss   Jul05   0:00 /usr/sbin/lvmetad -f
 root     51326  0.0  0.1 468332  5272 ?        Ssl  Jul05   6:37 /usr/sbin/rsyslogd -n
 root     51350  0.0  0.0  52852   848 ?        Ss   Jul05   0:00 /usr/sbin/smartd -n -q never
 root     51371  0.0  0.0  90668   568 ?        Ss   Jul05   3:56 /sbin/rngd -f
 polkitd  51530  0.0  0.0 610664  1548 ?        Ssl  Jul05   3:16 /usr/lib/polkit-1/polkitd --no-debug
 root     51561  0.0  0.0 582048  1620 ?        Ssl  Jul05   8:09 /usr/bin/python2 -Es /usr/sbin/tuned -l -P
 root     51610  0.0  0.0 124504   856 ?        Ss   Jul05   0:47 /usr/sbin/crond -n
 root     51638  0.0  0.0  24208   476 ?        Ss   Jul05   0:00 /usr/sbin/atd -f
 root     51956  0.0  0.0 226484   696 ?        Ss   Jul05   0:00 /usr/sbin/abrtd -d -s
 root     51980  0.0  0.0 225892   700 ?        Ss   Jul05   1:00 /usr/bin/abrt-watch-log -F BUG: WARNING: at WARNING: CPU: INFO: possible recursive locking detected ernel BUG at list_del corruption list_add corruption do_IRQ: stack overflow: ear stack overflow (cur: eneral protection fault nable to handle kernel ouble fault: RTNL: assertion failed eek! page_mapcount(page) went negative! adness at NETDEV WATCHDOG ysctl table check failed : nobody cared IRQ handler type mismatch Kernel panic - not syncing: Machine Check Exception: Machine check events logged divide error: bounds: coprocessor segment overrun: invalid TSS: segment not present: invalid opcode: alignment check: stack segment: fpu exception: simd exception: iret exception: /var/log/messages -- /usr/bin/abrt-dump-oops -xtD
 mysql    62681 20.6  9.1 1789944 354188 ?      Ssl  Jul05 8688:58 /usr/sbin/mysqld
 root      2977  0.0  0.1  39436  4328 ?        Ss   Jul06   7:43 /usr/lib/systemd/systemd-journald
 libstor+  3037  0.0  0.0   6668   440 ?        Ss   Jul06   0:16 /usr/bin/lsmd -d
 root      3052  0.0  0.0  24868  1412 ?        Ss   Jul06   5:34 /usr/lib/systemd/systemd-logind
 root      3068  0.0  0.0 108292   480 tty1     Ss+  Jul06   0:00 /sbin/agetty --noclear tty1 linux
 root      3155  0.0  0.0  43516   652 ?        Ss   Jul06   0:00 /usr/lib/systemd/systemd-udevd
 root      3205  0.0  0.0 195204   372 ?        Ssl  Jul06   0:00 /usr/sbin/gssproxy -D
 root      3289  0.0  0.0  21540   704 ?        Ss   Jul06   4:39 /usr/sbin/irqbalance --foreground
 root     29339  0.0  0.0  53264  1232 ?        Ss   Jul21   0:31 /usr/sbin/dovecot -F -c /etc/dovecot/dovecot.conf
 dovenull 29356  0.0  0.0  47464  3216 ?        S    Jul21   0:04  \_ dovecot/pop3-login
 dovenull 29357  0.0  0.1  49216  4368 ?        S    Jul21   0:50  \_ dovecot/imap-login
 dovecot  29358  0.0  0.0  10312   664 ?        S    Jul21   0:05  \_ dovecot/anvil
 root     29359  0.0  0.0  10560   932 ?        S    Jul21   0:09  \_ dovecot/log
 dovenull 29360  0.0  0.0  47756  3492 ?        S    Jul21   0:05  \_ dovecot/pop3-login
 dovenull 29362  0.0  0.1  49628  4736 ?        S    Jul21   1:18  \_ dovecot/imap-login
 root     29363  0.0  0.0  16360  2316 ?        S    Jul21   0:39  \_ dovecot/config
 dovecot  29364  0.0  0.0  13940  1268 ?        S    Jul21   0:14  \_ dovecot/stats
 dovecot  29544  0.0  0.0  10644  1076 ?        S    Jul21   0:14  \_ dovecot/imap-hibernate
 dovecot  58418  0.0  0.0  41476  3404 ?        S    17:47   0:00  \_ dovecot/auth
 winpet   60195  0.0  0.1  38340  3924 ?        S    18:02   0:00  \_ dovecot/imap
 mailnull 29427  0.0  0.0  85064  2228 ?        Ss   Jul21   0:10 /usr/sbin/exim -bd -q1h -oP /var/spool/exim/exim-daemon.pid
 root     29449  0.0  0.0 153400   816 ?        Ss   Jul21   0:03 pure-ftpd (SERVER)
 root     29451  0.0  0.0 152776   568 ?        Ss   Jul21   0:02 /usr/sbin/pure-authd -s /var/run/ftpd.sock -r /usr/local/cpanel/bin/pureauth
 root     10868  0.0  0.2 303804  9492 ?        Ss   Jul28   1:59 /usr/sbin/httpd -k start
 root     34427  0.0  0.0  12728   832 ?        S    Aug01   0:06  \_ /usr/local/cpanel/bin/splitlogs --dir=/etc/apache2/logs/domlogs --main=mail.winpet.com.tr --suffix=-bytes_log
 root     34428  0.0  0.0  12728   836 ?        S    Aug01   0:05  \_ /usr/local/cpanel/bin/splitlogs --dir=/etc/apache2/logs/domlogs --main=mail.winpet.com.tr --mainout=/etc/apache2/logs/access_log
 root     34429  0.0  0.2  53252  9752 ?        S    Aug01   0:00  \_ /usr/local/cpanel/3rdparty/bin/perl /usr/local/cpanel/bin/leechprotect
 nobody   34430  0.0  0.0 303772  3700 ?        S    Aug01   0:05  \_ /usr/sbin/httpd -k start
 root     34432  0.0  0.0 343052  3356 ?        Ssl  Aug01   0:02  \_ Passenger watchdog
 root     34436  0.0  0.1 882240  6268 ?        Sl   Aug01   0:35  |   \_ Passenger core
 nobody   42732  0.0  0.2 305976  9020 ?        S    15:34   0:00  \_ /usr/sbin/httpd -k start
 nobody   44844  0.0  0.2 305968  8836 ?        S    15:51   0:00  \_ /usr/sbin/httpd -k start
 nobody   44945  0.0  0.2 305836  8760 ?        S    15:52   0:00  \_ /usr/sbin/httpd -k start
 nobody   45365  0.0  0.2 305836  8924 ?        S    15:55   0:00  \_ /usr/sbin/httpd -k start
 nobody   45372  0.0  0.2 305968  8848 ?        S    15:55   0:00  \_ /usr/sbin/httpd -k start
 nobody   46355  0.0  0.2 305836  8608 ?        S    16:03   0:00  \_ /usr/sbin/httpd -k start
 nobody   47724  0.0  0.2 305972  8764 ?        S    16:15   0:00  \_ /usr/sbin/httpd -k start
 nobody   48404  0.0  0.2 305836  8484 ?        S    16:21   0:00  \_ /usr/sbin/httpd -k start
 nobody   48407  0.0  0.2 306020  8900 ?        S    16:21   0:00  \_ /usr/sbin/httpd -k start
 nobody   48974  0.0  0.2 305836  8348 ?        S    16:26   0:00  \_ /usr/sbin/httpd -k start
 nobody   49223  0.0  0.2 305968  8740 ?        S    16:27   0:00  \_ /usr/sbin/httpd -k start
 nobody   49295  0.0  0.2 305968  8564 ?        S    16:28   0:00  \_ /usr/sbin/httpd -k start
 nobody   49928  0.0  0.2 305836  8868 ?        S    16:34   0:00  \_ /usr/sbin/httpd -k start
 nobody   52429  0.0  0.2 305980  8628 ?        S    16:56   0:00  \_ /usr/sbin/httpd -k start
 nobody   52471  0.0  0.2 305836  8460 ?        S    16:56   0:00  \_ /usr/sbin/httpd -k start
 nobody   52920  0.0  0.2 305836  8628 ?        S    17:00   0:00  \_ /usr/sbin/httpd -k start
 nobody   54645  0.0  0.2 305836  8592 ?        S    17:14   0:00  \_ /usr/sbin/httpd -k start
 nobody   55454  0.0  0.2 305836  8224 ?        S    17:21   0:00  \_ /usr/sbin/httpd -k start
 nobody   56320  0.0  0.2 305836  8196 ?        S    17:28   0:00  \_ /usr/sbin/httpd -k start
 nobody   56354  0.0  0.2 305836  8540 ?        S    17:29   0:00  \_ /usr/sbin/httpd -k start
 nobody   56600  0.0  0.2 305836  8192 ?        S    17:31   0:00  \_ /usr/sbin/httpd -k start
```

I expect to writce in the terminal in command and make this problem solved but i dont know the solution yet.